# What's another way to say "Keep it on the horizon"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What can be another way to say keep it before you  or keep it on your horizon?

Comment: Is this a question of focus, or is your intention more about procrastination or putting it off?

Answer (score 3):

'Keep it on your radar' has a similar meaning of 'don't forget about it, but don't do anything about it yet'.

'keep it in mind'

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous phrases

> - keep your eye on the ball
> - maintain focus
> - keep it in your sights
> - be eagle-eyed
> - have a laser-like focus
> - keep it on your plate

Comment: I think *all* of these imply being *fully focussed* on [whatever it is]. But *keep it on your horizon* is invariably used to mean *don't forget all about it (**for the long-term**), even when you're busy with more pressing matters in the short-term*.

Comment: Thank you to all those who provided feedback.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about it or it will be coming your way soon.